# The concept of an electrically short, medium and long transmission line is primarily based on?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

The concept of an electrically short, medium and long transmission line is primarily based on ?

**A.** nominal voltage of the line
**B.** physical length of line
**C.** wave length of line
**D.** power transmitted over the line

Which option is correct? Why I Mean Explanation?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Comment: What do think which one is correct?

Comment: @Paul, I think B. I'm right?

Comment: @CuriousOne, I think B. I'm right?

Comment: http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Electrical+transmission+line

Comment: Why? Is a 100m line used to transmit an 800m wavelength signal electrically long?

Comment: @CuriousOne, I'm confusing can you explain answer with explanation?

Comment: It's in your textbook. Did you attempt to read the explanation?

Comment: @CuriousOne, little bit..

Answer (score 0):

The physical length of the transmission line in relation to the wavelength of the signal being propagated determines if the line is electrically long or short. It varies depending on the source, but typically, an electrically long line is at least 1/4 the length of the signal wavelength.